# NullPointerException in NavDrawerListAdapter for NavigationDrawer in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter, navigation-drawer

I am having a really strange problem. I am using a NavDrawerListAdapter for my NavigationDrawer in my Android App. If the list has 13 items (NavDrawerItem), it works OK. However, when I add a 14th element, the app appears to crash and give a NullPointerException. I checked the resources,strings,etc and everything appears to be correct. The stacktrace is pointing at this class inside getView() on the following line:

**imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());**

For some reason, the imgIcon is null.

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "NavDrawerListAdapter";
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private List<Boolean> enabledDrawerItems;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems) 
    {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
        this.mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Toggle enabled/disabled navigation drawer items
        enabledDrawerItems = new ArrayList<Boolean>(Arrays.asList(new Boolean[navDrawerItems.size()]));
        Collections.fill(enabledDrawerItems, new Boolean(true));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)   {
        if(position == 0)       {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_view, null);
            return convertView;
        }

        if(convertView == null)     {
            // Use the drawer list item view
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtCounter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

        Log.d(TAG, "Position: " + position + ", Icon Resource: " + navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
        Log.d(TAG, "NavDrawerItems: " + navDrawerItems.size());
        if(imgIcon == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "imgIcon is null");
        }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG, "imgIcon is not null");
        }

        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        if(navDrawerItems.get(position).isCounterVisible()){
            txtCounter.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        }
        else{
            txtCounter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if(enabledDrawerItems.get(position) == false)       {
            txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            convertView.setEnabled(enabledDrawerItems.get(position));
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()     {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position)  {
        return enabledDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    // Set state of navigation drawer item
    public void setNavigationDrawerItem(int pos, boolean enabled)   {
        enabledDrawerItems.set(pos, enabled);
    }
}
```

**strings.xml**

```
<array name="nav_drawer_icons">
        <item>@drawable/ic_home</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_people</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_photos</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_communities</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_pages</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_whats_hot</item>
    </array>
```

**NavigationDrawerActivity**

```
public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    public CharSequence mDrawerTitle; // nav drawer title
    public CharSequence mTitle; // store app title

    public TypedArray navMenuIcons; // menu item icons
    public String[] navMenuTitles; // menu item titles

    public ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems; // each drawer item
    public NavDrawerListAdapter adapter; // nav drawer adapter

    // Static Settings/Configuration
    private static final int NAVIGATION_DRAWER_WIDTH_PERCENT = 85; // in percentage
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public static final String INTENT_EXTRA_POSITION = "NavigationDrawerPosition";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Use ToolBar and set it as ActionBar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Get Nav Menu Icons and Titles
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // Get DrawerLayout and ListView
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        addNavDrawerItems(); // add each navigation drawer item

        // Recycle the array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        // setup the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                                                  mDrawerLayout,
//                                                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                                                  R.string.app_name,
                                                  R.string.app_name)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view){
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView){
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
            int drawerPosition = intent.getExtras().getInt(INTENT_EXTRA_POSITION);
            if(drawerPosition != 0) {
                // update selected item, title, and close drawer
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(drawerPosition, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(drawerPosition);
                setTitle(navMenuTitles[drawerPosition-1]);
            }
            else {
                Log.w(TAG, "drawerPosition is 0");
            }
        }

        mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle;

        configureNavigationDrawer();
        configureEnabledDisabledNavDrawItems();
    }

    private void configureEnabledDisabledNavDrawItems() {
        // Check if Device is connected (No: disable list item, Yes: enable list item)
        if(SecondScreenIAB.getInstance().getDevice() == null)
        {
            getAdapter().setNavigationDrawerItem(2, false); 
            getAdapter().setNavigationDrawerItem(3, false); 
        }
        else
        {
            getAdapter().setNavigationDrawerItem(2, true); 
            getAdapter().setNavigationDrawerItem(3, true); 
        }
    }

    private void addNavDrawerItems() {
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(0, "")); // Drawer Cover Image
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1), navMenuTitles[0]));             
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1), navMenuTitles[1]));             
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1), navMenuTitles[2]));             

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), navMenuTitles[3]));             
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1), navMenuTitles[4], "23", false));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), navMenuTitles[5]));             
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1), navMenuTitles[6], "5", false)); 

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1), navMenuTitles[7]));             

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1), navMenuTitles[8]));             
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), navMenuTitles[9]));             
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1), navMenuTitles[10]));            
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), navMenuTitles[11]));            
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1), navMenuTitles[12]));            

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1), navMenuTitles[13]));            
    }

    public void configureActionBar()    {
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Test");
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "Roboto-Regular.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        // Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(s);
    }

    private void configureNavigationDrawer()    {
        // Configure Navigation Drawer Width
        DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) mDrawerList.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * (NAVIGATION_DRAWER_WIDTH_PERCENT/100.0));
        mDrawerList.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    public ListView getmDrawerList() {
        return mDrawerList;
    }

    public void setmDrawerList(ListView mDrawerList) {
        this.mDrawerList = mDrawerList;
    }

    public NavDrawerListAdapter getAdapter() {
        return adapter;
    }

    public void setAdapter(NavDrawerListAdapter adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried adding resources of your icon in your Strings.xml ?

Comment: So there is one thing i should have mentioned. I have 6 icon resources. And I am recycling them. For example: NavDrawerItem #1 uses icon 1. #2 uses 2. #3 uses 3. #4 uses 4. #5 uses 5. #6 uses 6. #7 uses 1. #8 uses 2. #9 uses 3. #10 uses 4. #11 uses 5. #12 uses 6. #13 uses 1 .... etc

Comment: Yes of course you were, but have you defined icon Id for the last txtTitle you are defining ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using two different layouts:

- R.layout.header_view
- R.layout.drawer_list_item

I'm guessing that "R.layout.header_view" doesn't have "R.id.icon". So when it tries to reuse it, the imgIcon is null.

Base adapter has methods

```
public int getItemViewType (int position)
public int getViewTypeCount ()
```

You have two types of views. You need to make sure item at position 0 has a different type then the rest.

You would need to add these two methods to your adapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType (int position) {
    if(position == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount () {
    return 2;
}
```

And then update the first if statement in getView to:

```
    if(position == 0) {
        if(convertView == null)
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_view, null);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: When your using a list adapter it tries to reuse view when possible. You were creating two different types of view( i.e. one for the header and another for the rest) but the adapter didn't know about this, so it was trying to reuse the header view for another position. By adding these two methods you are telling the adapter I have two different types of views on for position 0 and another for the rest. So when it gives you a convertView now, it makes sure the it doesn't reuse the header view for another position. Hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove header from baseAdapter do as follows in main java having your baseAdapter to add your header

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_view, null); 

ListView listView = getListView();  
listView.addHeaderView(header); 
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: You can use @|-| method as well my method. They both will work :)